# Поиск совпадений в строке

Tags: php, строки

Народ помогите пожалуйста решить следующую проблему.Хочу написать небольшой разбор инвентаря для игры.Есть база данных с вещами и есть поток данных,в котором надо найти совпадения вещей из базы и их кол-во.Для начала идеально подходила функция **substr_count()**,но потом возникли моменты где она не могла помочь.Решил воспользоваться функцие **strpos()**.Вообщем подскажите как найти одинаковые названия вещей в этом потоке.

```
if(!empty($_POST['analys'])){
        $data = $_POST['analys'];
    }

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($things)){
        $thing = strpos($data,$result['name']);
    }
```

На сколько я понял надо вложенный цикл еще вписать,только пока не получается у меня.

Comment: а как этот "поток" выглядит? Приведите пример

Comment: Нападение (x14)  EF   (Масса: 0.14) 
Цена: 140.00 кр. 
Долговечность: 0/1
Вероятность срабатывания: 99%
Описание:
Позволяет вымещать накопившуюся агрессию на случайных прохожих.
Сделано в Abandoned Plain
Предмет не подлежит ремонту
 
 x24 
исп-ть
надеть Собрать Разделить Разделить поровну Добавить в избранное  Выбросить предмет Нападение (x24)  EF   (Масса: 0.24) 
Цена: 240.00 кр. 
Долговечность: 0/1
Вероятность срабатывания: 99%
Описание:
Позволяет вымещать накопившуюся агрессию на случайных прохожих.
Сделано в Abandoned Plain
Предмет не подлежит ремонту
Предмет из подземелья

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил всетаки

if(!empty($_POST['analys'])){
        $data = $_POST['analys'];
     }

```
 while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($things)){
    $offset = 0;
    $count = 0;

    do{
            $thing = strpos($data,$result['name'],$offset);
                if($thing!==false){
                $offset = $thing+1;
                $count++;
            }
    }

    while($thing!==false);
    echo $result['name']." - ".$count."</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($things){
  $str=$data;
  while(strpos($str, $result['name'])!==false){
    $arr[$result['name']]++;
    substr_replace($str, '', 0, strpos($str, $result['name'])+strlen($result['name']));
  }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Не работает этот код! Страница грузит постоянно что то,но ниче не выводит!